# Mysql views return data when table empty

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I am having a weird problem with mysql. I am developing a visual application on C# that stores data into a database. Previously I used SQL for the Database, but my client changed his mind for mysql. So I recreated the same schema on mysql. Now it is happening a really odd thing: My tables are completely empty, but when I execute the views, they return me back data from the old SQL tables, when I read directly from the tables they appear empty. The user that I use to connect are different and the most strange thing is that it happens even when I execute the view on mysql workbench. I have even truncated the tables in mysql and still the same thing. Does anybody know what may cause this anomaly and how to solve it?

p.s. Workbench version 6.2; Sql version SQL SERVER 2014

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, a view is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement.
It contains rows and columns, just like a real table in your database. The fields in a view are fields from one or more real tables in the database.

When you execute the views, they return back data from the old SQL tables. It is because your view still contains the data you run a while ago. You have forgotten to Drop your View every time you execute it. To Drop a MySQL view, try this one:

```
DROP VIEW view_name
```

Comment: i didn't knew this about mysql. I droped and recreated the view by adding a '2' to its name and still the same. I copy-pasted the view query from a notepad because it is a little bit long. It's not working

Comment: Delete your view and try to recreate it.

Comment: I did this and it worked: I copied the query from the view, executed it without the view name (as a simple query) so the dataset would get the new values and it worked. Before I had droped the view, recreated it with similar name, but I copy-pasted the query, so it was that the problem. Thanks for pointing out this fact about mysql

Comment: One more question: Considering that the view has its own dataset, may it cause problems when deleting rows from the table that it reads? Normally I would think this is a dumb question, with the knowledge I have over SQL Server, but the dataset fact was pretty surprising.

Comment: If you delete row from the table it reads, it will not affect the view unless you'll drop again your view and recreate it. It will not also cause problems in your SQl. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Views do NOT contain data of any kind -- except for Materialized Views and MySQL does not have those. If views had to be dropped and recreated every time a DML statement was executed on a table, views would be utterly useless.

The only time a view can return *old* data is when one process changes the contents of a table used in the view and the view is queried by another process before the first process commits the changes. You have not specified how the tables are being changed and how they are being queried. Nor have you included the `create view` statement. You could well be using other tables than what you think. This can happen during initial design of a database if tables are being slapped around like mad.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't post any query. at that moment I did not do any update, just copied the query from the sql server view and pasted it into the mysql create syntax. I had even restarted the pc because I suspected that it was something connected with the query's memory and still nothing. I recreated the view and slightly modified the query and it got solved. One thing I need to mention is that in the view's query, it had the table and fields with dbo.field and dbo.table. I will post tje previous query and the modified asap.